# What does this wavy line across a barline mean?

Tags: piano, notation, repeats

My daughter is playing *Ocarina of Time*, in an easy piano format.

The following sign appears at the end of the song:
[image: Wavy line]

Usually the song tells her to repeat and fade out but I have never seen this symbol before.  What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a standard musical notation.   If this is a piece that DOES end with a 'repeat and fade', I can accept it as meaning that.